# Moodle Database Connection Fail

Tags: installation, moodle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtyM4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI7uF.png)I try to install Moodle from Moodle installer.When i put the password for the database and click next ,show me this error.if I let empty the box of password I can continue to the next step. But I need a password in order to manage my database from phpmyadmin!!!

Comment: Could you provide more information on what exactly had you done before you encountered this error? Also, restrucure the post to clearly point out the question

Comment: I try to install Moodle from Moodle installer.When i put the password for the database and click next ,show me this error.if I let empty the box of password I can continue to the next step. But I need a password in order to manage my database from phpmyadmin!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty database first

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_an_empty_database

Looks like you need to create a database called `moodle` with user `root`